# Link nas tr da tabela

Tags: php, html

Bom, preciso que cada linha `tr` de minha tabela seja um link para quando a pessoa clicar redireciona para a página relacionada.

Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $timestamp = strtotime($linha['DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL']);
    $data = date('d/m/Y H:i', $timestamp);
    $titulo = $linha['TXT_TITUL_PUBLI'];
    $cdPublic = $linha['COD_IDENT_PUBLI'];
    echo "<a href='noticias.php?jr=$cdPublic'><tr>";
    echo "<td>$linha[TXT_TITUL_PUBLI]</td>";
    echo "<td>$linha[TXT_RESMO_PUBLI]</td>";
    echo "<td>$data</td>";

echo "</tr></a>";
}
```

Porem não esta dando link, como fazer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução é:

Adicionar

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).data('url');
        returnfalse;
    });
});
```

e na hora de chamar basta adicionar tbem a `tr` a tag `data-url`, ficando assim:

```
<tr data-url="seu-link-aqui.html">
```

O código onde está a tag `a` pode tirar do código.

--- Acrescentando conhescimento.

Para adicionar o ponteiro do mouse ao passar por cima da `tr`, basta adicionar esta linha:

```
style='cursor:pointer'
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom!! Nessas situações eu lhe recomendo a usar os eventos padrões das tags.
Nesse caso podes usar: *onclick* e depois passas o *location.href* que recebe o link.

**Veja a minha solução**

```
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $timestamp = strtotime($linha['DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL']);
    $data = date('d/m/Y H:i', $timestamp);
    $titulo = $linha['TXT_TITUL_PUBLI'];
    $cdPublic = $linha['COD_IDENT_PUBLI'];
    echo "<tr onclick=location.href='*'>";
    echo "<td>$linha[TXT_TITUL_PUBLI]</td>";
    echo "<td>$linha[TXT_RESMO_PUBLI]</td>";
    echo "<td>$data</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').click(function(){
        location.href = "noticias.php?jr=" + $(this).attr("data-destino")
    });
});

while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $timestamp = strtotime($linha['DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL']);
    $data = date('d/m/Y H:i', $timestamp);
    $titulo = $linha['TXT_TITUL_PUBLI'];
    $cdPublic = $linha['COD_IDENT_PUBLI'];
    echo "<tr data-destino='$cdPublic'>";
    echo "<td>$linha[TXT_TITUL_PUBLI]</td>";
    echo "<td>$linha[TXT_RESMO_PUBLI]</td>";
    echo "<td>$data</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assim fica simples e funciona sem usar js.

```html
$link = "https://google.com"; $link2 = "http://youtube.com"; echo "
<tr>"; echo "
  <td><a href='$link'> Google</a>
  </td>"; echo "
  <td><a href='$link2' target='_blank'> Youtube</a>
  </td>"; echo "</tr>";
```